# MongoDB find with $text index doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement a search for a user using his username, username fields are unique.
The result is to be all users whose username contains the string.
During the query, the 'q' parameter is correctly passed to the find () function, but when the 'q' parameter contains only a part of the username in the response, an empty array is returned.
However, when the whole username is given, the answer is correct.

My users.controller function:

```
async findAllUsers(req, res) {
    const sort_by = {};
        sort_by[req.query.sort_by || 'createdAt'] = req.query.order_by || 'desc';
        const offset = parseInt(req.query.offset) || 0;
        const per_page = parseInt(req.query.per_page) || 2;
        const usersPromise =
        User.find(req.filters)
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(per_page)
            .sort(sort_by);
        const countPromise = User.countDocuments(req.filters);
        const [users, count] = await Promise.all([usersPromise, countPromise]);
        return res.status(200).send({ data: users, count });
  }
```

My filter function:

```
export default function getFilters(req, res, next){
  const availableFilters = Object.keys(Users.schema.paths);
  const filters = qs.parse(req.query);

  const schemaFilters = _.pickBy(filters, (value, key) => availableFilters.indexOf(key) > -1);
  let searchFilter = {};
  if(filters.q){
    searchFilter = {
      $text: {
        $search: filters.q
      }
    }
  }

  req.filters = { ...searchFilter, ...schemaFilters };
  next(); 
}
```

My user model looks like this:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    minlength: 6,
  },
  password:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 8
  },
  email:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
  },
  description: String, 
  permissions: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    enum: [1, 2, 3],
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

User.index({ username: 'text' });

export default mongoose.model('User', User);
```

and my route looks like this:

```
  api.get("/users", getFilters, catchAsync(usersController.findAllUsers));
```

Example of user in db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fba87e118f11129905aea93"),
    "username" : "Brody_Muller",
    "password" : "$2b$10$Smb9HP5dIINvO0.6K48PkOTXpXn9Tu.H.218XRIHOMOUthrWNCk7C",
    "email" : "Mariane.Crist@gmail.com",
    "age" : 44,
    "description" : "Voluptas deserunt occaecati ut perferendis qui temporibus.",
    "permissions" : 3,
    "createdAt" : "2020-11-22T15:46:37.777Z",
    "updatedAt" : "2020-11-22T15:46:37.777Z"
}
```

I also tried to create an index in the describtion field, but here neither searching for part of string nor searching for whole string was unsuccessful.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search does not work like that. It's probably more complicated than this, but it seems the [only simple inferences are done](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#stemmed-words).

"blue", it won't match blueberry; however, "blueberry" will match blueberries.

You can still create a standard index on the `username`, and then use regex, like so:

```
 db.test1.find({username:/Brody/})
```

This will match the query. You can improve things use insensitive search too, and making it the start of the word `/^Brody/i`.

---

Extended from comments. [MongoDB on "stop words"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words):

> text indexes drop language-specific stop words (e.g. in English, the, an, a, and, etc.) and use simple language-specific suffix stemming.

Solution for this is:

```
db.coll.createIndex({description:"text"},{language:"none"})
```

> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text index uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I was just wondering if it might be better to use `$regex` for this.
If I understand correctly, `$search` searches for whole words with with slight differences.
I understand that if I am looking for a user whose 'description' field consists of strings separated by spaces like this:
`Sed amet dolorum excepturi molestias et dolorem aut laborum`
using `$search` to find `et` will also not work?

Comment: @Avend47 You got it right. If you look for $search "et" it will. But if your search term is "something_else" then partial search won't work.

Comment: @Avend47 `et` won't work. Cause it's a "stop word". They are not indexed. Added the reference docs. All  normal words do work. Ex.`dolorum excepturi molestias`. To avoid this, create the index using `none`. Added code too.